# javascript InnerHTML adding cards only one time

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add a bootstrap card inside a div called [**itemscontainer**] using javascript
by `document.getElementById("itemscontainer").innerHTML` so i want the cards to be inserted inside the `itemscontainer` only one time like this :-

[image]

but the problem is the items cards keeps reapet them salves more than one time like:-

[image]

what i want is to clear the `itemscontainer` first before adding the cards and this is what i have tried so that the items will be only one cards for each item

```
// clear function
    function clear(){
        document.getElementById("ssst").innerHTML = ""
    }
    // listener append all items to the inventory
    window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
        let data = event.data
        if(data.action == 'insertItem') {
            let name = data.items.name
            let count = data.items.count
            let icon  = data.items.icon
            if(document.getElementById("ssst").innerHTML == ""){
                clear()
            }else{
            document.getElementById("ssst").innerHTML += 
                "<div class='card holder'>"+
                        '<div class="card-body">'+
                            '<img src="icons\\'+icon+'" style="position:absolute;left:15%;width:40px; height:36px;" alt="">'+
                            '<h4 id="counter">'+count+'</h4>'+
                        '</div>'+
                        '<span class="itemname">'+name+'</span>'+
                '</div>";'
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: You clear code makes no sense. So you need to see if you added the element before you add it to the DOM. Sounds like your message comes back more than once so you need to see if it does. Could be an issue with how you bind things if it only ever should come back once. Hard to guess from the small amount of code provided.

Comment: `+=` adds the HTML, it doesn't replace.

Comment: @Barmar what should I use instead? `==`?

Comment: Use `=` instead. That will replace the div contents instead of appending to it.

Comment: @Barmar The OP is clearly adding more than one image and there is no loop, so that is not going to work.

Comment: @epascarello Yeah. So it's not clear when it's supposed to clear.

Comment: So if you want to add multiple images to the div, when is it supposed to clear? Is there some other button that should do this?

Comment: There is no process flow that clearly shows when the `message` event is fired.  Without that, any answer is likely to make incorrect assumptions about the high level logic involved.  Please update the question to include this information.

Comment: @Tibrogargan Message Event is called from another script in `Lua language` called  `SendNUIMessage({
 items = argument,
 action = "insertItem"
    })`

Comment: This information is insufficient.  You are not supplying anything about *why* and *when* the event is fired.  Frankly it's irrelevant **how** it occurs.  Please edit the question and add that information, people will not see it in the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real solution is to figure out why you are getting the items more than once. With the information you provided that is impossible for me to answer. So the only thing we can recommend is how to prevent items from being added more than once.

If your messaging system returns duplicates you can determine if you have seen it. If you do, replace it. Otherwise add it.

```js
window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  const data = event.data;
  console.log(data)
  if (data.action == 'insertItem') {
    let name = data.items.name
    let count = data.items.count
    let icon = data.items.icon

    const html = `
      <div class='card holder' data-name="${name}">
        <div class="card-body">
          <img src="icons/${icon}" style="position:absolute;left:15%;width:40px; height:36px;" alt="${icon}">
          <h4 id="counter">${count}</h4>
        </div>
        <span class="itemname">${name}</span>
     </div>`;

    const elemExists = document.querySelector(`[data-name="${name}"]`);
    if (elemExists) {
      const parser = new DOMParser();
      const doc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
      elemExists.replaceWith(doc.body);
    } else {
      document.getElementById("ssst").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", html);
    }
  }
});




window.postMessage({
    action: 'insertItem',
    items: {
      name: 'foo',
      count: 1,
      icon: 'foo'
    }
});

window.postMessage({
    action: 'insertItem',
    items: {
      name: 'bar',
      count: 40,
      icon: 'barrrrrr'
    }
});


window.postMessage({
    action: 'insertItem',
    items: {
      name: 'foo',
      count: 1000,
      icon: 'foo'
    }
});
```

```html
<div id="ssst"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Why are you using the if statement, what are you checking for?

remove the if statement, I can't see the reason for it to be used here.

clear()

and the rest of your code.

Comment: i have removed the statmeant and tired what you said and when i test it the first itemcard is only added to the div